# VS 2017 Community gets linker errors but Professional doesn't

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2017

We're facing a strange issue and I've run out of troubleshooting ideas.  The issue is that on some machines, which are running Visual Studio 2017 Community, we get reports that our project (which is CMake based) gets linker errors like this:

```
17>------ Build started: Project: ndt, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64 ------
17>   Creating Library E:/NDT_3_0/19_Sept18/qualnet/RelWithDebInfo/exata_so.lib and object E:/NDT_3_0/19_Sept18/qualnet/RelWithDebInfo/exata_so.exp
17>ndt-main-windows-x64-vc14.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol edKJPOs664VT referenced in function "void __cdecl CheckLibraryLicenses(struct NodeInput*,...)
17>ndt-main-windows-x64-vc14.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol zzPIPSGJWa referenced in function main
...
17>E:\NDT_3_0\19_sep18\qualnet\bin\exata_so.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals
```

(Apologies if there are typos: for some reason they sent us a screenshot of the text instead of just a copy-and-paste of the text, so I'm transcribing.  However, the parts I'm leaving out contain no mention of errors trying to open `lmgr.lib` which defines these symbols.)

The strange thing is, we can't reproduce these errors here when we do a fresh clone of the same Bitbucket repository they're using and follow the same build instructions.  About the only difference I can tell is that our machines are running Visual Studio 2017 Professional.  (Though I'm certainly not sure if this is actually the cause of the behavior differences.)

So far, what we've checked:

- The library that contains the unresolved external symbols passes sha1sum checks so their Git client isn't corrupting the library binary file `lmgr.lib` - and same for the `ndt-main-windows-x64-vc14.obj` file.
- The generated `ndt.vcxproj` project contains (the correct path to) `lmgr.lib` in the "Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies" property, as expected.
- The `lmgr.lib` file does define the mentioned symbols (verified by Cygwin binutils `nm`).
- On their machines, they get essentially the same linker errors whether using the `Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64` generator and building from the IDE, or using the `NMake Makefiles` generator and building from a command prompt.  Both configurations work fine on our machines.

I was wondering if somebody out there might have any ideas on why some machines might be failing to find the symbols in `lmgr.lib` whereas our machines have no problems completing the link stage.

(Possibly relevant: `lmgr.lib` contains the FlexNet Publisher licensing libraries where the symbols in both `lmgr.lib` and `ndt-main-windows-x64-vc14.obj` have been obfuscated by Flexera's `lmstrip` tool.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that when we asked them to upgrade their Visual Studio 2017 Community installation to the latest service pack release, then after that the linker errors disappeared.